# How to configure Xamarin.Google.iOS.TagManager?

Tags: google-analytics, xamarin.ios, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to use Xamarin.Google.iOS.TagManager component in my Xamarin App and I configured it following the "Getting Started" documentation that is provided alongside it.

I can see my events tracked in Firebase console Analytics.

However, I do not see any events in Google Analytics. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a confirmed bug in the Xamarin.Google.iOS.TagManager component 5.0.6.2. It is discussed as an issue over where the component is maintained on github: https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/61